# What do these Webpack v3 ModuleConcatenationPlugin bailout messages mean?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-3

I get this output with Webpack 3, using `ModuleConcatenationPlugin`:

```
  [11] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
       ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
  [54] multi ./src/index.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
       ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
  [55] ./src/index.js + 33 modules 238 kB {0} [built]
       ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is referenced from these modules with unsupported syntax: multi ./src/index.js (referenced with single entry)
```

Webpack's own file (`(webpack)/buildin/global.js`) prevent concatenation?

`src/index.js` looks like this:

```
import Calendar from './Calendar'
import DoubleSidedPlane from './DoubleSidedPlane'
import Grid from './Grid'
import Molecule from './Molecule'
import Plane from './Plane'
import PushMenuLayout from './PushMenuLayout'

import * as utils from './utils'
import * as core from './core'
import * as html from './html'
import * as components from './components'

export {
    Calendar,
    DoubleSidedPlane,
    Grid,
    Molecule,
    Plane,
    PushMenuLayout,

    utils,
    core,
    html,
    components,
}

export const version = '17.0.4'
```

Comment: What does your .babelrc look like?

Answer (score 0):

global.js doesn't prevent concatenation for all modules. The error means these particular modules aren't concatenated. You will need ES6 modules to make the ModuleConcatenationPlugin work.